# Find and list files from last 3-days starting from midnight of first day

Tags: shell, find

please assist, I am trying to list the files from last 3 days in directory starting from midnight of first day from last 3-days. I created this so far " find ./* -type f -mtime -3 -exec ls {} ;" This only pulls data from current time to - 3days. It doesn't get data from midnight of first day. I need a data start from last 3-days starting midnight to today.

Please assist.
thank you

Comment: You're looking for the `-daystart` predicate.

Comment: Whoever closed this as a dup, the -daystart option doesn't appear on all versions of find.

Answer (score 0):

You can touch a file with the earliest date you want to use. Then use find's -newer option.

```
touch -t <earliestDate> someTempFile
find . -type f -newer someTempFile -exec ls -l {} \;
```

You don't need -exec if you execute ls with no options and you're constrained to normal files.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i don't want to hardcode any date. Instead i would like to get data from last 3-days starting from the midnight of the first day that is 00:01 etc. please assist is there any way to creat the "someTempFile" with eralistDate starting from 00:00.

Comment: Here is what i have done so far.                                                                               
# touch --date "-3 days" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' someTempFile                                                # find stm* -type f -newer someTempFile -exec ls {} \; > ./myfiles.txt
Output:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user1 23 Dec 27 02:58 someTempFile                                                      Q: if created someTempFile file stamp will be 00:00 instead 02:58 will solve request.  please assist. thanks